# Vertically center slick slider navigation arrows

Tags: slick.js

I have a slick slider carousel where I have images and a caption. If captions are short and in one line the navigation arrows are perfectly aligned vertically. However, if captions take up more that one line the navigation arrows comes down and it looks a bit strange.

The issue here is that the arrows have a css top: 50% and they get aligned with the container. But in my situation I would like them to be vertically aligned only with the images not with the images+caption. So, independently of how much content I would have bellow each image on each slide the arrows would always be vertically aligned with only the image. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Do you have an example, or maybe create a fiddle we can view?

Comment: I have ended up aligning both arrows on top left, so they always stay on that position independently of the content height.